# Using theMovieDB to display Image Poster with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, themoviedb-api

I'm new to using the themoviedb JSON api, and I'm currently trying to do something that seems simple: Display a movie's main poster. I got an API key and here is the code / response I'm using.

```
$ca = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=MYAPIKEY");
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ca, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($ca);
curl_close($ca);
//var_dump($response);
$config = json_decode($response, true);
//print_r($config);
//$base = $config['base_url'];
//echo($base);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=Monsters+University&api_key=MYAPIKEY");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
//print_r($result);
//var_dump($response);
echo("<img src='" . $config[0]['base_url'] . $config[0]['poster_sizes'][2] . $result[0]['poster_path'] . "'/>");
```

My only question now is I'm trying to echo a  tag to display the poster, but I'm not sure what the correct code would be would it be something like this?

```
$responsePHP = json_decode($response);
echo("<img src='" . $responsePHP['poster_path'] . "'/>");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Added the config array, but it the echo returns with nothing. The JSON for both print out fine and `print_r` seems to work with `json_decode`, I just don't know why I can't pull out any values from the arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you need to do an additional request to `/3/configuration` in order to get some extra info.

The parameter you are looking for is `base_url` which you can use to construct the urls.

Read more here: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fconfiguration

You may be wondering why is that required. According to their site, they did it so they can keep their API light, and it seems the `base_url` rarely changes (see https://www.themoviedb.org/talk/515a72d0760ee3615a0b5256 for more)

So, you could do that request only once every X time (like once a day for instance) and then use the `base_url` I get there in all the subsequent requests I may need to do.

---

**EDIT:** Sigh, I thought you had problems only for not having the `base_url`, not with getting the data from the json.

### Anyway, just replace the last line to this:

```
echo("<img src='" . $config['images']['base_url'] . $config['images']['poster_sizes'][2] . $result['results'][0]['poster_path'] . "'/>");
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you're close.  you have to grab the base_url from configuration just like you did for the movie query (http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#configuration) and prepend the base_url to what you have and then you also need the poster or backdrop size. it should be something like this:

```
echo("<img src='" . $config['base_url'] . $config['poster_sizes'][2] . $responsePHP['poster_path'] . "'/>");
```

so the output should be something like:
http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/2lECpi35Hnbpa4y46JX0aY3AWTy.jpg

Comment: Check my edit. Something is still not working with pulling values out from the arrays.

Comment: if you uncomment your print_r($config); line, what is displayed?

Comment: try to change your "config" section to this (sorry about the formatting):

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);

    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

    $error_number = curl_errno($ch);
    $error_message = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    $config = json_decode(($results),true);

Answer (score 0):

The following will print out the poster path.  I think that's what you want.

```
$responsePHP = json_decode($response);
$movies = $responsePHP->results;
$firstMovie = $movies[0];
echo $firstMovie->poster_path;
```

If your question is about how to get the base_url then look at vadderung's answer.

Comment: Check my edit, for some reason values are not being pulled out of the arrays when I request them, is there some syntax I'm missing?

Comment: @Vikram: You are missing array keys. Here's the link for what you want: [http://pastebin.com/Efp05kUV](http://pastebin.com/Efp05kUV).  I still recommend you use object notations like I showed in my original example.